# How to update the app silently without asking user option and how to customise package installer?

Tags: android

During update the app silently, they asking permission to user. When I try to set permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

in AndroidManifeast.xml. They throws error as "Permission only granted for system app". Is their any way to update silently or how to convert my app as system app?

Comment: You cannot install APPLICATIONS without user's explicit permission; not unless the device and your program is rooted.

Comment: if you're doing a test on your own, copy the apk file to /system/app directory and try doing the operation. If you want to make it available to users, like the previous comment said, you cannot install apps without user consent.

Comment: how play store automatically update the app silently?